# Saving the PDF output file into a specific file using pdflatex inside VisualStudio C#

Tags: pdftex, pdf, miktex, output

I am trying to run a .tex file using pdflatex with MikTex from inside VisualStudio C#. My problem is that I can't seem to get the PDF output in the right location. I saw that there is the "-output-directory" option but I haven't been able to implement it correctly.

I am running the following line:  `Process.Start("pdflatex", pathTEX);` to get the PDF. Can someone give me an example of how to properly add the output directory into the code line I have or any other method? Thanks in advance